# Jquery: How to find individual sets of numbers in a string of text and add href tags to them

Tags: jquery, string, text, replace, href

I've got several strings of text with numbers that are meant to connect to other entries in the index (using hashes, as they will be on a page together). For example:

```
<div class="description"><span>This is some text, which we will reference in entry (330) and also in entry (249).</span></div>
```

I've been able to get the numbers to show up, separated by a comma, but I'm not able to get them to separate in relation to adding the links, and I'm actually not entirely sure how I should go about wrapping them with a href without replacing the text around them. This is where I'm at so far, but I've hit a wall.

```
        var val = $("description span").html();
        var numbers = val.match(/\d+/g);
        if (numbers != null) {
           console.log(numbers);
          //here goes the separate and wrap code that eludes me.
        }
```

intended result:

```
<div class="description"><span>This is some text, which we will reference in entry (<a href="myindex.html#330">330</a>) and also in entry (<a href="myindex.html#249">249</a>).</span></div>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You are missing a `.` in `$("description span")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comment you are missing a `.` in your selector, except from that you can try something like:

```
$.each(numbers, function(n, t) {
  $(".description span").html($(".description span").html().replace(t, "<a href='#" + t + "'>" + t + "</a>"))
})
```

**Demo**

```js
var val = $(".description span").html();
var numbers = val.match(/\d+/g);
if (numbers != null) {
  $.each(numbers, function(n, t) {
    $(".description span").html($(".description span").html().replace(t, "<a href='#" + t + "'>" + t + "</a>"))
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="description"><span>This is some text, which we will reference in entry (330) and also in entry (249).</span></div>
```

Comment: A speedy, spot-on answer. Thank you so much! If you don't mind my asking, just so I can understand how your code works, what is the purpose of the function(n, t) if the n goes unused.

Comment: @Niwa `n` represents the index and is unused, but we use t and that represent the object, in this case 330 and 249